# Проблема с переводом SQL-запроса в Entity Framework

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6

Имеются таблицы Product и Price, таблица цен содержит внешний ключ Price.ProductId для таблицы Product. Таблица цен содержит информацию о ценах на каждый продукт, эти цены могут быть изменены в соответствии с StartDate, другими словами, пользователь может назначить новую цену для любого продукта с точной StartDate. Как это можно реализовать с помощью Entity Framework? Модель сущностей Product имеет коллекцию сущностей из таблицы Price, но нецелесообразно извлекать такое количество сущностей Price, потому что продукт должен быть связан только с фактической ценой в окончательном запросе.

Есть 2 модели, которые отображают таблицы

```
public partial class Product
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Price> Prices { get; set; }
}

public partial class Price
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long ProductId { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

Невозможно извлечь полную коллекцию Product.Prices, с Product должна быть связана только одна фактическая цена. Похоже, что SQL-запрос ниже может извлекать данные, но как это можно сделать с помощью EF?

```
select public.price., public.product. from public.product  
inner join public.price on public.price."ProductId" = public.product."Id"
where public.price."Id" in 
(
    select max(public.price."Id") from public.price
    where public.price."StartDate" <= current_date 
    group by  public.price."ProductId" 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможность выполнения такого запрос сильно зависит от провайдера данных и версии EF.
Интуитивно он должен выглядеть как-то так, но не ручаюсь за работоспособность в неизвестном окружении.

```
context.Prices
.Where(x => x.StartDate <= currentDate)
.GroupBy(x => x.Product, x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.StartDate).First())
.ToArrayAsync()
```